# Need to return values from class method using reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

In my Winform the user has the option to pick sets of colors depending on the button clicked.

The colors themselves are stored in a different class. Using reflection the Method that is called depends on the the button clicked while all buttons use the same event.

Code in form:

```
private void Button_Theme__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    string[] Color = Regex.Split(button.Name.ToString(), "_");

    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    ColorTheme ColorTheme = new ColorTheme();
    MethodInfo ColorMethod = thisType.GetMethod("ColorTheme.Theme_" + Color[2]);

    Color[] ColorThemes =  (Color[])ColorMethod.Invoke(this, null);
    ColorThemeLight = ColorThemes[0];
    ColorThemeMedium = ColorThemes[1];
    ColorThemeDark = ColorThemes[2];     
}
```

Code in the class:

```
public Color[] Theme_Yellow()
{
    ColorThemeLight = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 200);
    ColorThemeMedium = Color.FromArgb(255, 191, 191, 150);
    ColorThemeDark = Color.FromArgb(255, 127, 127, 100);
    Color[] Colors = { ColorThemeLight, ColorThemeMedium, ColorThemeDark }; 
    return Colors;
}
```

I am getting the following error but i can't seem to pinpoint where the problem lies and how to fix it. 
[image]

Comment: `thisType.GetMethod("ColorTheme.Theme_" + Color[2])` - ColorTheme is not a part of method name. maybe `thisType.GetMethod("Theme_" + Color[2])` ?

Comment: ColorTheme is the name of the class that is being called :)

Comment: ColorTheme is the name of the class that is being called, but ColorTheme is not a part of method name

Comment: Then how do i reference the class where the method is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to use reflection, you need correct `Type` and method name:

```
private void Button_Theme__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    string[] Color = string.Split(button.Name, "_");

    MethodInfo ColorMethod = typeof(ColorTheme).GetMethod("Theme_" + Color[2]);

    ColorTheme theme = new ColorTheme();
    Color[] ThemeColors = (Color[])ColorMethod.Invoke(theme, null);
    ColorThemeLight = ThemeColors [0];
    ColorThemeMedium = ThemeColors [1];
    ColorThemeDark = ThemeColors [2];     
}
```